# Stopping async function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an asynchronous function which can last a long time and I want to allow the user to end the function at any point. Currently my function looks like this and it is bad design.

```
bool stopRun = false;

Future run() async {
  await doX();
  if(stopRun) return;
  await doY();
  if(stopRun) return;
  await doZ();
  if(stopRun) return;
  ...
}
```

Basically I change the `stopRun = true` when I want to end the function. This has multiple issues.

1. The `run` function gets hard to update.
2. The function waits `doX()`, `doY()` and `doZ()` to finish.
3. I can only run a single `run` function at a time.

Does dart offer something which could fix the issues I have? Is there a better way to design this kind of function?

**I have tried:**

CancelableOperation in this way but it does not end the run method.

```
var cancellableOperation = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
        run(),
        onCancel: () => {},
    );
cancellableOperation.cancel();
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any easy way to handle this automatically.  I would recommend rewriting `run` to be a state machine, and on each iteration through the machine, check `stopRun` before transitioning to the next state (or replace `stopRun` with a transition to some terminal state).

Comment: @flutter_rowen you to put doX(), doY() in cancellableOperation future instead of run, because on cancel run method in cancellableOperation it will stop run method but inner future is still running

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can cancel Future in dart by using [CancelableCompleter](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableCompleter-class.html)

Example -

```
var myCancelableFutureX = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
 doX(), { FutureOr onCancel()? });

var myCancelableFutureY = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
  doY(), { FutureOr onCancel()? });

var myCancelableFutureZ = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
  doZ(),  { FutureOr onCancel()? }  );

  onCancelPress(){
 // call the cancel() method to cancel the future
    myCancelableFutureX.cancel();
    myCancelableFutureY.cancel();
    myCancelableFutureZ.cancel();
}
```

Here is well explained tutorial on [CancelableOperation](https://www.kindacode.com/article/ways-to-cancel-a-future-in-flutter-and-dart/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have to say it's kind of ugly that I need to create a lot of cancelableOperations. I do not believe that this is anyway easier than just checking stopRun after each function. Also I cannot just replace the run() method with it's contents because I have to able to call the run() from multiple classes.